# Matroid of monomials of linear forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, matroid-theory

Consider the linear matroid $M(k, d)$ on the monomials of degree $d$ in $k$ general linear forms $L_1, \ldots, L_k$ in two variables, over $\mathbb{C}$. For simplicity take $k=3$ and the forms $X, Y, X+Y$, which are already general after acting by $PGL_2$. These give

$$M(3, d) = \{X^a Y^b (X+Y)^c : 0 \leq a, b, c \text{ and } a+b+c = d\}.$$
The ground set is effectively a big standard simplex,
$$L(3, d) = \{(a, b, c) : 0 \leq a, b, c \text{ and } a+b+c = d\}.$$

**Question:** Is there a simple combinatorial description of the rank function of this matroid?

(I have tagged this question as algebraic-geometry as well as matroids because this comes from some calculations involving linear series on $\mathbb{P}^1$.)

There are various minimal relations / circuits such as

$$X^n + Y^n = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} (-1)^i c_i X^i Y^i (X+Y)^{n-2i}$$
where $c_i = \binom{n-i}{i} + \binom{n-i-1}{i-1}$ and $c_0 = 1$; see http://oeis.org/A157000.

Actually, this relation can be deduced to exist by triangularity+symmetry considerations without explicitly finding the coefficients.

Similarly, any $d'+2$ elements having a gcd of degree $d-d'$ must be linearly dependent: they live in a copy of $M(3, d')$ inside $M(3, d)$. This amounts to examining subtriangles of $L(3, d)$.

But, these are not all the circuits; for instance the two circuits above can be combined to make other circuits.

Comment: This article by Stroh may be useful https://www.digizeitschriften.de/download/pdf/235181684_0031/log43.pdf

Comment: If we restrict to the line $X+Y=1$, then we consider monomials $X^aY^b$ modulo $X+Y-1$. So, any dependence corresponds to a polynomial divisible by $X+Y-1$. All such polynomials are linear combinations of $X^i Y^j(X+Y-1)$, which gives many circuits of size 3. The problem is that there may exist cancellations when you sum up such circuits.

Comment: Do you mean to take $M(k,d)$ to be the linear matroid, and what is the ground field?

Comment: Yes, the linear matroid. I'll edit the question. I am over $\mathbb{C}$.